# [ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SSL Security error (18)

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server using pyodbc 4.0.30 with Python 3.7. Everything was going great the past couple of days until today when I get this error:

> OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SSL Security error (18) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()). (1)')`

My connection:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('driver={SQL Server};server=redacted;database=uipcc_awdb;uid=redacted;pwd=redacted;trusted_connection=no;')
```

**Please note** I can connect normally to the database via SQL Server Management Studio, and no changes were made on my machine, the SQL Server, or the network.

I need to emphasize, I have tried to following which were mentioned in similar questions (but none worked):

- adding `sslverify=0` in the connection parameters
- adding `encrypt=0` in the connection parameters
- Changing the OBDC drivers from my machine, didn't work and ruined the connection from SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Does it work if you use `Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};` in your connection string? Ref: [Step 3: Proof of concept connecting to SQL using pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc)

Comment: >>>trusted_connection=no<<< get rid of this. you pass userid and password, this parameter should not be passed at all

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/a/65924760/1467396 -> "Try changing the driver parameter from "SQL Server" to "SQL Server Native Client 11.0". This led to a successful connection for me." (and it worked for me, too)

Comment: AlwaysLearning, thank you very much. Using Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} helped me perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Try enabling TLS 1.0 on your registry at this location:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS1.0\Client\
```

For eg:

[image]

Change it to:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a TLS version issue. TLS 1.0/ TLS 1.1 has probably been disabled on the SQL Server.

There is currently an open issue on the [pyodbc github tracker](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/788)

And see this other question:
[Pyodbc giving exception with older version of sql driver but failing with latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62554776/pyodbc-giving-exception-with-older-version-of-sql-driver-but-failing-with-latest)

Comment: Is there a solution or workaround for this? For example, will it work if I disable TLS1.0/1.1 on the client?

Comment: As an interim work-around you might try to re-enable TLS 1.0/1.1 on the server

Comment: I have no access on the server. Is there anyway to match it from the client?

Answer (score 0):

Check your driver.  My app was using an older driver version.  When the server/network was upgraded, the app failed (in my case it was perl) - upgrading to latest sqlserver driver and specifying `TrustServerCertificate=yes` in the connection string worked.